# rails one liner active records depends on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what I want to query is somethinkg like

`Model.where(condition: params[:condition])` if `params[:condition]` exists.

otherwise its okay to return all.

I came up with one liner like `Model.where(condition: params[:condition] || 0..Float::INFINITY)`

but it didn't work.

`Model.where(condition: 0..Float::INFINITY)` works as I expected, so I thought above also would work.

Do you guys have any good idea to query by oneliner?　I know ternary operator should work.

Answer (score 1):

`params[:condition] || (0..Float::INFINITY)` will only return `(0..Float::INFINITY)` in the case that `params[:condition]` is `nil` or `false`:

```
{ condition: "" }[:condition] || (0..Float::INFINITY)
# => ""
{ condition: false }[:condition] || (0..Float::INFINITY)
# => 0..Infinity
{ condition: nil }[:condition] || (0..Float::INFINITY)
# => 0..Infinity
```

You could use [`Object#presence`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) to check if the value is not `false`, is empty, or a whitespace string:

```
{ condition: "" }[:condition].presence || (0..Float::INFINITY)
=> 0..Infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

> otherwise its okay to return all

As I understand you need different scopes depend on condition

You can use chaining in that case

For example

```
models = Model.all
models = models.where(condition: params[:condition]) if params[:condition]
```

So if `params[:condition]` is truthy: some `where` scope will be used

If not: all records will be used

It's not one liner. But quite convenient